# Get [year month day] of difference between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
import datetime

difference = (datetime.date(2020, 1, 15) - datetime.date(1987, 7, 15))
```

'''This gives return as days but I want this as `[year, month, day]` format.        The result must be accurate. '''

Answer (score 0):

run

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

try the below code

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta


date1 = datetime(2020, 1, 15)
date2 = datetime(1987, 7, 15)

diff = relativedelta.relativedelta(date1, date2)
years = diff.years
months = diff.months
days = diff.days
print('{},{},{} '.format(years, months, days))
```